# How to add custom format button using Quill and Angular?

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I want to add Quill editor with or without ngx-quill library in my Angular 7 application and customize it.
How to add a custom button with a custom icon on the Quill toolbar and add logic to it? For example, this button will wrap the highlighted word in a tag?

```
    <div class="green-word">highlighted word</div>
```